# heading for row and col for data structure matrix in R programming

Tags: r

[image]Consider you want to implement a 3x3 matrix in R, and wish to have row names and col names. What would be the appropriate code for it ?

I tried using row bind and col bind functionality but unable to figure out how to add a unique heading for each row and col.

Comment: rownames(), colnames() Allows you to change the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
matrix(1:9, 3, 3, dimnames=list(letters[1:3], LETTERS[1:3]))
#   A B C
# a 1 4 7
# b 2 5 8
# c 3 6 9
```

Note the first character vector provides the row names and the second provides the column names.

Comment: I've added an image, please take a look as I need to implement exactly that.

Comment: Simply `rownames(YourMatrix) <- c("SNDL", "WRN", "NGD", "UPH", "WISH")` and the same for  `colnames()`.